# Какой самый идеальный вариант webp заменить на jpg если не поддерживает браузер?

Tags: css, webp

Какой самый идеальный вариант `webp` заменить на `jpg` если не поддерживает браузер?

```
body {
    background-image: url(../images/image.webp);
    background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
}

<img src="/images/image.webp">
<img src="/images/image.jpg">
```

Хотелось бы получить идеальное решение без `JS`, так как по поиску тут везде с `JS` предлагают.

Или можно на JS, но самым минимум кода.

Предложите варианты которые существуют

Comment: тег `<picture>`

Comment: @meine, это только для `img`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkWebP(callback){
  let webP = new Image();
  webP.onload = webP.onerror = function(){
    callback(webP.height == 2);
  };
  webP.src = 'data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjoAAABXRUJQVlA4IC4AAACyAgCdASoCAAIALmk0mk0iIiIiIgBoSygABc6WWgAA/veff/0PP8bA//LwYAAA';
};
checkWebP(function(support){
  if(support) document.body.classList.add("webp");
  else document.body.classList.add("no-webp");
});
```

```css
body.webp {
  background: url("img/bg.webp");
}
body.no-webp {
  background: url("img/bg.jpg");
}
```